# How to stop gulp watch running in windows powershell

Tags: powershell

Sorry if this is an easy question but I'm running gulp watch in windows powershell, which all works fine. What I don't know is how to stop the watch process from running. If I start gulp watch and then want to install another package for example I have to restart powershell which is a pain.

Thanks, David

Comment: Depending on how you're starting gulp: Ctrl+C

Comment: Thank you ctrl+c worked :-)

Comment: In many cases the script freezes when I press Ctrl+C but  I see a message at the bottom saying "Stopping" in PowerShell ISE. Any ideas?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - You need to add that as an answer :)